# Provision EC2 node: gets destroyed as soon as it is ready

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have added an EC2 cloud with the intention of using Windows instances.
The Windows AMI is configured to use SSH connection, not WinRM.
When I provision a Windows instance, I see it starting in the AWS console, and I see this in the Jenkins console:

```
May 07, 2021 5:45:42 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connecting to ec2-18-197-156-192.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 5:45:52 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Failed to connect via ssh: The kexTimeout (10000 ms) expired.
May 07, 2021 5:45:52 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
May 07, 2021 5:45:57 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connecting to ec2-18-197-156-192.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 5:45:57 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Failed to connect via ssh: There was a problem while connecting to ec2-18-197-156-192.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22
May 07, 2021 5:45:57 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
```

(repeat many times)
This is normal of course, as long as the instance is still starting.

After a while, I see in the AWS console that the instance is Running.
And immediately, it gets terminated.

I also see this in the Jenkins log, which may or may not be relevant:

```
May 07, 2021 5:50:52 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2OndemandSlave lambda$terminate$0
Terminated EC2 instance (terminated): i-0c82439628de13743
May 07, 2021 5:50:52 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2OndemandSlave lambda$terminate$0
Removed EC2 instance from jenkins master: i-0c82439628de13743
```

This is when I manually provision:

```
May 07, 2021 6:18:25 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate getImage
Getting image for request {ExecutableUsers: [],Filters: [],ImageIds: [ami-0d8ed2b0df1b1c6ef],Owners: []}
May 07, 2021 6:18:25 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate logProvisionInfo
SlaveTemplate{description='Windows', labels='aws windows'}. Considering launching
May 07, 2021 6:18:25 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate setupRootDevice
AMI had /dev/sda1
May 07, 2021 6:18:25 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate setupRootDevice
{DeleteOnTermination: true,SnapshotId: snap-0ab3c9f92925a0abf,VolumeSize: 200,VolumeType: gp2,Encrypted: false}
May 07, 2021 6:18:25 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate logProvisionInfo
SlaveTemplate{description='Windows', labels='aws windows'}. EBS default encryption value set to: Based on AMI (null)
May 07, 2021 6:18:25 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate logProvisionInfo
SlaveTemplate{description='Windows', labels='aws windows'}. Setting Instance Initiated Shutdown Behavior : ShutdownBehavior.Terminate
May 07, 2021 6:18:25 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate logProvisionInfo
SlaveTemplate{description='Windows', labels='aws windows'}. Looking for existing instances with describe-instance: {Filters: [{Name: image-id,Values: [ami-0d8ed2b0df1b1c6ef]}, {Name: instance-type,Values: [t3a.medium]}, {Name: key-name,Values: [rsa-8192-aws-jenkins]}, {Name: tenancy,Values: [default]}, {Name: subnet-id,Values: [subnet-d426f499]}, {Name: instance.group-id,Values: [sg-0c2d470529c492f13]}, {Name: tag:jenkins_server_url,Values: [https://jenkins.itextsupport.com/]}, {Name: tag:jenkins_slave_type,Values: [demand_Windows]}, {Name: tag:Name,Values: [Jenkins/Windows]}],InstanceIds: [],}
May 07, 2021 6:18:26 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate logProvisionInfo
SlaveTemplate{description='Windows', labels='aws windows'}. Return instance: {AmiLaunchIndex: 0,ImageId: ami-0d8ed2b0df1b1c6ef,InstanceId: i-0078ac5df5320de3d,InstanceType: t3a.medium,KeyName: rsa-8192-aws-jenkins,LaunchTime: Fri May 07 18:18:26 CEST 2021,Monitoring: {State: pending},Placement: {AvailabilityZone: eu-central-1c,GroupName: ,Tenancy: default,},Platform: windows,PrivateDnsName: ip-172-31-12-78.eu-central-1.compute.internal,PrivateIpAddress: 172.31.12.78,ProductCodes: [],PublicDnsName: ,State: {Code: 0,Name: pending},StateTransitionReason: ,SubnetId: subnet-d426f499,VpcId: vpc-ddb7aab5,Architecture: x86_64,BlockDeviceMappings: [],ClientToken: e9f54d34-c9a4-47db-a472-a1204e9b5784,EbsOptimized: true,EnaSupport: true,Hypervisor: xen,ElasticGpuAssociations: [],ElasticInferenceAcceleratorAssociations: [],NetworkInterfaces: [{Attachment: {AttachTime: Fri May 07 18:18:26 CEST 2021,AttachmentId: eni-attach-0789ae7127addb88f,DeleteOnTermination: true,DeviceIndex: 0,Status: attaching,NetworkCardIndex: 0},Description: ,Groups: [{GroupName: ssh,GroupId: sg-0c2d470529c492f13}],Ipv6Addresses: [],MacAddress: 0a:1a:df:ec:e0:26,NetworkInterfaceId: eni-034d777e34991680a,OwnerId: 050520292612,PrivateDnsName: ip-172-31-12-78.eu-central-1.compute.internal,PrivateIpAddress: 172.31.12.78,PrivateIpAddresses: [{Primary: true,PrivateDnsName: ip-172-31-12-78.eu-central-1.compute.internal,PrivateIpAddress: 172.31.12.78}],SourceDestCheck: true,Status: in-use,SubnetId: subnet-d426f499,VpcId: vpc-ddb7aab5,InterfaceType: interface}],RootDeviceName: /dev/sda1,RootDeviceType: ebs,SecurityGroups: [{GroupName: ssh,GroupId: sg-0c2d470529c492f13}],SourceDestCheck: true,StateReason: {Code: pending,Message: pending},Tags: [{Key: Name,Value: Jenkins/Windows}, {Key: jenkins_slave_type,Value: demand_Windows}, {Key: jenkins_server_url,Value: https://jenkins.itextsupport.com/}],VirtualizationType: hvm,CpuOptions: {CoreCount: 1,ThreadsPerCore: 2},CapacityReservationSpecification: {CapacityReservationPreference: open,},Licenses: [],MetadataOptions: {State: pending,HttpTokens: optional,HttpPutResponseHopLimit: 1,HttpEndpoint: enabled},EnclaveOptions: {Enabled: false},}
May 07, 2021 6:18:26 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2RetentionStrategy start
Start requested for EC2 (eu-central-1 Windows) - Windows (i-0078ac5df5320de3d)
May 07, 2021 6:18:26 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Launching instance: i-0078ac5df5320de3d
May 07, 2021 6:18:26 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
bootstrap()
May 07, 2021 6:18:26 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Getting keypair...
May 07, 2021 6:18:26 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Using private key rsa-8192-aws-jenkins (SHA-1 fingerprint 87:87:34:8e:a4:d5:7f:17:bb:08:9d:f8:68:c9:33:f1)
May 07, 2021 6:18:26 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Authenticating as jenkins
May 07, 2021 6:18:27 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connecting to null on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:18:27 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
No SSH key verification (ssh-ed25519 57:02:49:51:15:8a:41:70:67:ca:7a:e5:48:5f:32:b6) for connections to EC2 (eu-central-1 Windows) - Windows (i-0078ac5df5320de3d)
May 07, 2021 6:18:27 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connected via SSH.
May 07, 2021 6:18:27 PM WARNING hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Authentication failed. Trying again...
May 07, 2021 6:18:57 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Authenticating as jenkins
May 07, 2021 6:18:57 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connecting to ec2-3-66-217-65.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:19:00 PM INFO hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer tryReconnect
Attempting to reconnect aws-linux-node-eu-central-1-packer
May 07, 2021 6:19:07 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Failed to connect via ssh: The kexTimeout (10000 ms) expired.
May 07, 2021 6:19:07 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
May 07, 2021 6:19:12 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connecting to ec2-3-66-217-65.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:19:22 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Failed to connect via ssh: The kexTimeout (10000 ms) expired.
May 07, 2021 6:19:22 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
May 07, 2021 6:19:27 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connecting to ec2-3-66-217-65.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:19:37 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Failed to connect via ssh: The kexTimeout (10000 ms) expired.
May 07, 2021 6:19:37 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
May 07, 2021 6:19:42 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connecting to ec2-3-66-217-65.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:19:47 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
No SSH key verification (ssh-ed25519 78:ed:18:5b:52:00:76:72:8e:ae:73:69:3c:69:31:dd) for connections to EC2 (eu-central-1 Windows) - Windows (i-0078ac5df5320de3d)
May 07, 2021 6:19:47 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connected via SSH.
May 07, 2021 6:19:48 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
connect fresh as root
May 07, 2021 6:19:48 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connecting to ec2-3-66-217-65.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:19:48 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
No SSH key verification (ssh-ed25519 78:ed:18:5b:52:00:76:72:8e:ae:73:69:3c:69:31:dd) for connections to EC2 (eu-central-1 Windows) - Windows (i-0078ac5df5320de3d)
May 07, 2021 6:19:48 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Connected via SSH.
May 07, 2021 6:19:49 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Creating tmp directory (/tmp) if it does not exist
May 07, 2021 6:20:07 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Verifying: java -fullversion
May 07, 2021 6:20:12 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Verifying: which scp
May 07, 2021 6:20:14 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Copying remoting.jar to: /tmp
May 07, 2021 6:20:15 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
Launching remoting agent (via Trilead SSH2 Connection):  java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /tmp/remoting.jar -workDir C:\Users\jenkins
May 07, 2021 6:20:18 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2OndemandSlave lambda$terminate$0
Terminated EC2 instance (terminated): i-0078ac5df5320de3d
May 07, 2021 6:20:19 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2OndemandSlave lambda$terminate$0
Removed EC2 instance from jenkins master: i-0078ac5df5320de3d
```

And in the console log of the instance:

```
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Launching instance: i-02435726c827f7a6a
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: bootstrap()
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Getting keypair...
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Using private key rsa-8192-aws-jenkins (SHA-1 fingerprint 87:87:34:8e:a4:d5:7f:17:bb:08:9d:f8:68:c9:33:f1)
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Authenticating as jenkins
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connecting to null on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: No SSH key verification (ssh-ed25519 57:02:49:51:15:8a:41:70:67:ca:7a:e5:48:5f:32:b6) for connections to EC2 (eu-central-1 Windows) - Windows (i-02435726c827f7a6a)
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connected via SSH.
May 07, 2021 6:29:46 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
WARNING: Authentication failed. Trying again...
May 07, 2021 6:30:16 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Authenticating as jenkins
May 07, 2021 6:30:16 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connecting to ec2-52-29-72-22.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:30:26 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Failed to connect via ssh: The kexTimeout (10000 ms) expired.
May 07, 2021 6:30:26 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
(...)
May 07, 2021 6:31:01 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connecting to ec2-52-29-72-22.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:31:09 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: No SSH key verification (ssh-ed25519 78:ed:18:5b:52:00:76:72:8e:ae:73:69:3c:69:31:dd) for connections to EC2 (eu-central-1 Windows) - Windows (i-02435726c827f7a6a)
May 07, 2021 6:31:09 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connected via SSH.
May 07, 2021 6:31:09 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: connect fresh as root
May 07, 2021 6:31:09 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connecting to ec2-52-29-72-22.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:31:13 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: No SSH key verification (ssh-ed25519 78:ed:18:5b:52:00:76:72:8e:ae:73:69:3c:69:31:dd) for connections to EC2 (eu-central-1 Windows) - Windows (i-02435726c827f7a6a)
May 07, 2021 6:31:13 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connected via SSH.
May 07, 2021 6:31:13 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Creating tmp directory (C:\\Windows\\Temp\\) if it does not exist
[91mNew-Item: [91mAn item with the specified name C:\Windows\Temp already exists. [0m
May 07, 2021 6:31:28 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Verifying: java -fullversion
openjdk full version "11.0.11+9"
May 07, 2021 6:31:32 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Verifying: which scp
/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/scp
May 07, 2021 6:31:34 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Copying remoting.jar to: C:\\Windows\\Temp\\
May 07, 2021 6:31:35 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Launching remoting agent (via Trilead SSH2 Connection):  java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar C:\\Windows\\Temp\\/remoting.jar -workDir C:\Users\jenkins





HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found

URI:    /computer/EC2%20(eu-central-1%20Windows)%20-%20Windows%20(i-02435726c827f7a6a)/logText/progressiveHtml
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE:    Not Found
SERVLET:    Stapler
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I was using the same ssh keys on the master and on the node. Mine was coming online but builds were not executing on the node but on the master.

I worked out that when trying to connect to the node it was connecting to ssh on the localhost (master).
This bit from your log-

```
INFO: Connecting to null on port 22, with timeout 10000.
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: No SSH key verification (ssh-ed25519 57:02:49:51:15:8a:41:70:67:ca:7a:e5:48:5f:32:b6) for connections to EC2 (eu-central-1 Windows) - Windows (i-02435726c827f7a6a)
May 07, 2021 6:29:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connected via SSH.
```

I changed my ssh key for the node and then I started getting the same as you, the node would be killed off as soon as it was connected.

My work around to fix this was to change the ssh port on the master to anything other than 22 so that it couldn't connect to localhost first.

You could either change the master ssh port or the node but changing the master is the easier option without creating a new ami for the node.